# Google Compute Engine :Email solution

Tags: email, smtp, google-compute-engine, emailrelay

Google compute engine blocks outgoing smtp . The only option it gives in it's documentation is using sendgrid.

I have my own mailserver for transactional emails and other emails as well .

Can i Use another mail server ( not on google ) and create an smtp relay on compute engine ( on port other than 25 ) to forward port 25 traffic to that server ?

if so , how ?

Answer (score 0):

See [Googles documentation on this](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail), I use [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com) and Postfix to send email from my GCE instance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports but port 25, which is blocked because of the risk of abuse. All other ports are open, including ports 587 and 465.

You can use third party provider such as SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet

For sendgrid: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid

For Mailgun: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun

For Mailjet: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet